# What's the difference between Bluegrass and Country?

Tags: genre, folk, country, genre-characteristics, bluegrass

I'm diving into North American folklore music of the 20th century, and two of the staples are the Bluegrass and Country genres / styles.

They seem to be intimately connected though, so: How are they different? How are they related?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bluegrass is a sub-genre of Country Music with characteristics that differentiate it from mainstream Country:

- The instrumentation is purely 'string band' based: Guitar, Banjo, Mandolin, Fiddle and Upright Bass. There is more emphasis on an 'acoustic' sound.
- The music is more free and the structures are more complex. Elements of other styles like Jazz or Blues are incorporated, there are more improvised instrumental solos.
- The voices are mostly arranged in three part harmony (sometimes two or four) with a distinctive sound in the high voice, sometimes called the "high lonesome sound".
- Some people say Bluegrass has more of a 'hillbilly' style, a label disliked by Bluegrass musicians.
- There are distinctive playing styles on the various instruments: flatpicking on the guitar, three-finger picking on the banjo, a characteristic fiddle sound with thirds and fifths.

Here are some examples of the style

- Earl Scruggs ["Foggy Mountain Breakdown"](https://youtu.be/yQIJuu3N5EY)
- Ricky Skaggs ["Country Boy"](https://youtu.be/xzImpR_HF7U) (But untypically using piano and electric bass)
- Bill Monroe "["I'm Working on a Building"](https://youtu.be/yBDZ3G4RCHc) (The typical vocal sound)

Comment: I'll add my favorites beneath this fine answer: Bill Monroe & The Bluegrass Boys - Southern Flavor (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NcCgsAMxhs) and Nitty Gritty Dirt Band feat. Earl Scruggs - Nashville Blues (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzO78hKSctQ).